# Facebook native comments VS Plugin comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I have a web site with a number of articles; each article appears in a page that has a Facebook comment plugin and a unique canonical URL.

For example canonical URL: http://domainABC.com/articlenumber

This is what the plug in tag looks like (I’ specifically using .NET 4.0, but the question is regardless of the language or the platform)

[ div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%=URL_Canonical()%>" data-numposts="50" data-width="620" ]

Where URL_Canonical() is a unique url identifier related ot each of the articles in my database.

The question:

When a user shared my article on Facebook using the URL_Canonical and the same user of others comment on the article, are these comment supposed to appear on the plugin that is in my page.

I understand that comments left on the page using the plug in can be (if the user decides to) posted to the user wall, does the other way around works? Do the comments left on Facebook related to an article will appear on the article plugin in the external site? 
Thank for any help.